# Using a loop to insert pictures to Word using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm trying to use a loop to shorten the last part of my VBA code.

The current code I have is:

```
Sub InsertPics()

Dim WordApp as Object
Dim WordDoc as Object

Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("Testing.docx"

WordApp.Visible = True

Dim path() as Variant
Dim i as Long
Dim Pic as Variant

path = Application.Transpose(Sheets("Selection").Range("N10:N24").Value)
For i = LBound(ppath) To UBound(ppath)
    path(i) = Sheets("Output").Range("Directory").Value & "\" & path(i) & ".jpg"
Next i

Set Pic1 = WordDoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(path(1), False, True).ConvertToShape
Set Pic2 = WordDoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(path(2), False, True).ConvertToShape
Set Pic3 = WordDoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(path(3), False, True).ConvertToShape

End Sub
```

The `Set Pic()` part goes on for quite awhile so I'm looking for a way to do the same sub with a shorter code. Is there a way to loop this part?

Note: `WordDoc` refers to a specific word document, `path()` refers to a list of directory addresses that I've already defined.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your pictures in a list too. See R3uK's `collection` proposal.

But if you don't need to keep a reference on your pictures, you can make it even simpler:

```
For i = 1 To 3
  WordDoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(path(i), False, True).ConvertToShape
Next
```

Comment: Thanks J. Chomel, I tried your code but got a Type mismatch error.

I had a look at the Locals window and it shows that the value for Pic is empty. How should I define Pic if the first time that I'm using it is to insert the pictures? 

I currently only have path()  defined as Variants with the directory values saved.

Cheers.

Comment: `Pic()` should be defined a similar way you defined `path()`.

Comment: Hi J.Chomel. I've edited the post to show the full code for better clarity. I actually used `Application.Transpose` to first define path() - thanks to another stackoverflow user's help. Do you know what code I can use to define Pic()?

Comment: If you don't use `Pic1` etc. you might not even need the `Pic()` part.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array or a collection :

```
Sub test_volvader()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim myCol As Collection
    Set myCol = New Collection

    For i = 1 To 3
        myCol.Add WordDoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(Path(1), False, True).ConvertToShape, i
    Next i

    For i = 1 To myCol.Count
        YourOperationOnAPicture myCol.Item(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```